# PHP: Any good way of handling sometimes empty arrays?

Tags: php, html, arrays

I'm returning an array from my DB with something like 0,0,1,0 which would be chosen products in this case. With that I'm checking if I should mark an element as selected.

`$p` gets the array with the product group. Then for a series of elements I use something like this.

```
<input <?= $p[0]=='1'?'checked':'';?> value="Product 1" />
<input <?= $p[1]=='1'?'checked':'';?> value="Product 2" />
<input <?= $p[2]=='1'?'checked':'';?> value="Product 3" />
<input <?= $p[3]=='1'?'checked':'';?> value="Product 4" />
```

But sometimes no choice has been made at all, which would return an empty array, which in turn triggers php errors like `Uninitialized string offset: 3`

What would be a good way to handle empty arrays while keeping the markup rather tidy? Separate functions or so?

---

**UPDATE**

Updated solution, which with 4 radios results in the first three of them checked.

```
<?php $p=check(1); ?>

<input type="radio" <?= !empty($p[0])?'checked':'';?>>
<input type="radio" <?= !empty($p[1])?'checked':'';?>>
<input type="radio" <?= !empty($p[2])?'checked':'';?>>
<input type="radio" <?= !empty($p[3])?'checked':'';?>>
```

**>** And the sql query result might not even be an empty array. I guess if the query doesn't result in anything, not even an empty array is set as a result?

Comment: you really should stop using the <?= syntax. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/200640/are-php-short-tags-acceptable-to-use

`<?php echo isset($p[0]) && $p[0]=='1' ? 'checked' : ''; ?>`

Comment: @Rufinus bad advice [Since PHP 5.4.0, <?= is always available.](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php). Note also that php 5.3 is already end of life, so 5.4 is the current version of php - it's appropriate to use unless legacy support is a concern.

Comment: @Rufinus I would not say he should stop using them. He should learn about the possible disadvantages and decide. For example, I use them most of the time.

Comment: ok ok ...  <?= is fine... and according to docs, <?= is not considered a short tag :D

Comment: @Rufinus, PHP has flip-flopped on their stance on *short tags* through versions. However, there is a difference between short output tags and short open tags. Generally [I avoid both](http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2012/08/better-php-developer/).. But, `<?=` is the lesser of two evils :)

Comment: @JasonMcCreary agreed

Comment: I generally use `<?php` except for inline code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [`empty()`](http://php.net/empty):

```
<input <?= !empty($p[0]) ? 'checked' : ''; ?> value="Product 1" />
```

From the docs:

> No warning is generated if the variable does not exist. That means empty() is essentially the concise equivalent to !isset($var) || $var == false.

Since `0` is a [false value](http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php), this works in your case.

Comment: Would be slightly clearer logic to invert the inline if in that case `<?= empty($foo) ? '' : 'checked'` - i.e. avoid double negative logic (if it's not-not-empty echo "checked"). +1

Comment: @AD7six, agreed. I would personally do that, but wanted to keep the OP's original logic.

Comment: That solution just gives me 3 checked radios. `$p` gets the raw db result, if that makes any difference.

Comment: What I provided is just an example to get your started. If you are still having trouble, update your post with the updated code.

Comment: You will need to invert your logic if you are using `empty()` vs. `!empty()`. See **AD7six**'s comment.

Comment: Tried `<?= empty($p[0])?'':'checked';?>` but that just gave me the same first three checked radios. As I mentioned, maybe the sql result isn't even an empty array if the sql query returns zero results.

Comment: You should post another question regarding your SQL results. Your original question has been answered.